# +Finding Dynamic Programming Values & Weights+

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

+++
We are given the following table on the number of homeless people in each of 3 cities, where *n* the number of homes to be built.

```
City    n=0  n=1  n=2
 A       15   12   10
 B        9    8    4
 C        8    6    5
```

We are after a housing strategy that minimises the total numbers of
homeless people across all 3 cities for a given number of homes.
What would be the optimal allocation of *n* homes to homeless, and how many homeless would that result in total?
The solution is to employ dynamic programming & be in Python.
It appears like an unbounded knapsack problem with capacity *n* but what is hard to find are the values & weights to be used as parameters of the algorithm.
Please share your views.
+++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+++
I have managed to solve the task as a bounded knapsack case with multiple values as follows.

---

```
def assign_home(cpct, tbl):
    ctNum = len(tbl[0])
    wghts = [1] * ctNum
    vls = get_vls(tbl)
    hms = [0] * ctNum
    HMSBND = 2
    hmlsVal = [sum(row[0] for row in tbl) for hmIndx in range(min(cpct + 1, ctNum * HMSBND + 1))]
    for hmIndx in range(min(wghts), min(cpct + 1, ctNum * HMSBND + 1)):
        chsn = -1
        for ct, wght in enumerate(wghts):
            if wght <= hmIndx and hms[ct] < HMSBND and hmlsVal[hmIndx] > hmlsVal[hmIndx - wght] - vls[ct][hms[ct]]:
                hmlsVal[hmIndx] = hmlsVal[hmIndx - wght] - vls[ct][hms[ct]]
                chsn = ct
        if chsn != -1:
            hms[chsn] += 1
    return hmlsVal[min(cpct, ctNum * HMSBND)], hms

def get_vls(tbl):
    [A, B, C] = tbl
    Adf = [A[0] - A[1], A[1] - A[2]]
    Bdf = [B[0] - B[1], B[1] - B[2]]
    Cdf = [C[0] - C[1], C[1] - C[2]]
    return [Adf, Bdf, Cdf]

tbl=[[15, 12, 10], [9, 8, 4], [8, 6, 5]]
print(assign_home(5, tbl))
# (20, [2, 2, 1])
```

+++